# PDFTextStripper extracts incorrect Thai text

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, truetype

I have problem that pdfTextStripper read my pdf in a wrong encoding (or may be greek character). And I don't know how to set it. Any help?

```
PDDocument my_document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile.getInputStream(), password);
PDFTextStripper pdfTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
pdfTextStripper.setWordSeparator("|");
pdfTextStripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(false);
return pdfTextStripper.getText(my_document);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share the PDF, mention what PDFBox version you are using, include any log messages you get in your question, and read the text extraction FAQ: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm using PDFbox 2.0.13 . I'm so sorry I didn't have any pdf file that can  be shared, but the problem is that when I read the Thai language in the file. Somehow, they put special characters like (?,) in  the content instead of the "vowel" in Thai language

Comment: The current version is 2.0.14 but that shouldn't make a difference. What do you get when doing copy & paste of it with Adobe Reader? And how do you store the text after returning it? (If it is in a file, it must be encoded e.g. as utf8)

Comment: *"pdfTextStripper read my pdf in a wrong encoding"* - usually this is due to the PDF itself claiming an incorrect encoding or no encoding at all.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have created sample file of my own [link](https://ufile.io/btesm) You can try it out.

Comment: There's a problem with some modifying glyph, "ชื่อบัญชี นาย ทดลอง วรรณยุ้กต์" (in Adobe Reader) appears as "ช่ือบัญชี นาย ทดลอง วรรณยุก้ต ์ ". Probably a PDFBox bug, but difficult to fix for us westerners :-(

Comment: @TilmanHausherr it's okay. Thank you very much

Comment: Issue created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4481